# How to create dummy varab

Tags: r

i have a monthly data about air quality Pm10 of Zajci and wanting to create a dummy variable 0 prior to May 2017 and 1 After May 2017

current code

[image]

data

[image: data]

```
ZAQ <- read_excel("rmit/FQA/ZAQ.xlsx", col_types = c("date", 
                                                     +     "numeric", "numeric")) 
ZAQ <- ZAQ |> mutate(date = date(Day)) |> mutate(month= yearmonth(Day)) |> mutate(year = year(Day))
ZAQ1 <-  aggregate( Pm10 ~ month + year, ZAQ, mean)
ZAQ2 <- as_tsibble(ZAQ1, index=month)
ZAQ2 %>% mutate(data_trat = cut(mdy(month), breaks = as.Date(c("2017-5-27")), 
                                labels = c(0, 1)))
```

Comment: i am not really good at this. My assignment does not require it to be effiecient, just need to work and i'm struggling to do it TT.

Comment: Makes no sense to use a "Date"-valued break in `cut` on a "yearmonth"-valued field since it's likely to fail in the absence of a `cut` method for items of class `yearmonth`. Why not do the `cut` with the `Day` column??? BTW, it's considered extremely poor form to post data in the form of images. You should read [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with efficiency. If you want to do a `cut`, there needs to be a vector with class "Date" or "POSIXct". There's no `cut` method for vectors of class "yearmonth". Please read ALL of my points in the comment.

Comment: i did have a dummy column before i took the mean of daily to a monthly. But when i did the 'aggregate' it deleted the Dummy column. How about can i do a "POSIXct" year column to do cut.

Comment: to be frank, you should speak to your tutors about this, (i know from personal experience they aren't great, but you should at least try)

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(month = c("2017 Apr", "2017 May", "2017 Jun"))

df |> 
  mutate(
    yearmonth = ym(month),
    dummy = as.integer(yearmonth >= "2017-05-01")
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   month    yearmonth  dummy
#>   <chr>    <date>     <int>
#> 1 2017 Apr 2017-04-01     0
#> 2 2017 May 2017-05-01     1
#> 3 2017 Jun 2017-06-01     1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>